# How to generating uniqId up to 9 digits without characters

Tags: php, random, timestamp

I want to generate a unique number based on time stamp.
Each request must have a unique number different from all other requests within a twenty four hour period.

Any ideas how can I generate it lets say up to 9 digits number?

Comment: If you can rate-limit to one request per millisecond, you can use "HHMMSSmil". That's nine digits.

Comment: You can't really be sure you have a *unique* number if you don't compare it with all the others being used in the same time window, unless you limit your requests as Thilo suggested (but depending on your case that could be not desirable).

Comment: Why only numbers? And why exactly 9 digits? If you want a unique value then you would be better off with huge random values, base64 encoded for portability.

Comment: Just a clarification, why would you like the unique number to be based on `timestamp`? You know, current timestamp is already 10 digits long...

Comment: @Eggplant: 10 digits is also okay I think

Comment: I can base on something else rather than timestamp but I need to have unique id for interval time of 24 hours

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: I am using an api which allowing only numbers for unique id

Comment: @Thilo: Can you explain in more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 global types of solution:

1. Store all the unique IDs on one place and there generate/increment them. Best example: store the request in (MySQL) database where index is autoincrement.
2. The other solution is to try and calculate the unique ID based on microtime. As an example for this option we could use directly:

   ```
   filter_var($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
   ```

   which will return 9-13 chars in string, or we could take a unique string using PHP's [uniqeid function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

   ```
   $my_id = uniqid();
   ```

   > Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in
   >   microseconds.

   Since it is based on microtime, than the return value is 13 character long.

   In case you want it be more unique, than you can also use prefix this way:

   ```
   $my_id = uniqid( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
   ```

   but than the return value will be longer.

Comment: `uniqid` gives a unique id which can contain characters... I need only numbers

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
echo rand(1,999999999);die;
```

but 9 digits for unique number will not be enough, it depends on the amount of unique keys you want to generate

Comment: Random != unique. Also, you should use `mt_rand()`, not `rand()`.

Comment: thats why i said that it depends of the context you want to use the unique.

Comment: Why voting negative ??

Comment: The question was about a **unique** number. Your answer creates a **random** number. This answer is not useful. Please use the comments if you need more information, before giving an answer.

Comment: `mt_rand()` uses the [Mersenne Twister algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), whereas `rand()` uses an [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). The former is better in almost every way.